# Plotting the PDF of a Binomial distribution

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the histogram and pdf of `2 X - 100` with `X` a binomial distribution, but I'm having trouble with the pdf -- I just get a line `y = 0`. I tried ploting a simple binomial distribution, but I don't get anything with that either and it takes so much time.

```
Li[n_] := 2*RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[n, 1/2], n] - n;
Tb[n_, m_] := Table[Li[n], {i, 1, m}];
y = Tb[100, 1000];
Show[ 
 Histogram[y, 40, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[2*BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2] - 100, x], {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

Comment: That's (among other things) because giving `...2*BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2]-100...` as the argument to `PDF` is nonsense. I suggest you avail yourself of the documentation to understand how to properly utilize the probability functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you're not using the functions properly. I *think* what you're after is:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[TransformedDistribution[2*z - 100, 
                 z \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2]], x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Note the use of `DiscretePlot` - the binomial is a *discrete* distribution, so a discrete plot is appropriate. You can cajole things to use `Plot`, but that's goofy IMO...

Comment: @ciao...the quick or the dead...just deleting my response :)

Comment: @ubpdqn: Lol, once again, you cause me to spit-laugh my tea onto my netbook. Cleaning now....

Comment: "…but that's goofy…" - Hyuck! :)